# Postgres not using index in simple query

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a simple table storing a few values.

```
    create table customer_usage
(
    id           bigserial                              not null
        constraint customer_usage_pk
            primary key,
    customer_id  bigint                                 not null
        constraint customer_usage_customer_id_fk
            references crm.customer,
    profile_id   bigint                                 not null,
    supplier_id  bigint                                 not null,
    direction    smallint                               not null,
    pod          varchar                                not null,
    trunced_date date                                   not null,
    period_end   timestamp with time zone               not null,
    usage_wh     real                                   not null,
    created_at   timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);
create unique index customer_usage_id_uindex
    on customer_usage (id);

create index customer_usage_profile_id_index
    on customer_usage (profile_id);

create index customer_usage_supplier_id_index
    on customer_usage (supplier_id);

create index customer_usage_trunced_date_index
    on customer_usage (trunced_date);

alter table edm.customer_usage cluster on "customer_usage_trunced_date_index";
```

When I try to query data for for a specific "trunced_date" the explain plan shows, that it is NOT using the clustered index for this very column.

```
explain analyze select * from edm.customer_usage where trunced_date = '2021-05-26';
```

Explain plan:

```
QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on customer_usage  (cost=0.00..48792.40 rows=1495664 width=92) (actual time=0.053..20115.107 rows=1494912 loops=1)
  Filter: (trunced_date = '2021-05-26'::date)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 254880
Planning Time: 0.370 ms
Execution Time: 37914.739 ms
```

I don't understand, why -- in the simplest query asking specifically for one column that has a clustered index -- this index is not used.
Thank you very much for your help.

Fritz

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: @PeterHenell If you read the explain plan closely, you'll see that this information is included there.

Comment: @fritz are you able to run vacuum and retry? Also - is it possible that significant amount of trunced_date = '2021-05-26' will be returned?

Comment: Hi, indeed, significant amount of data is for this date:
` select trunced_date, count(1) from edm.customer_usage group by 1; ` `trunced_date,count`
`2021-05-26,1494912`
`2021-07-01,67872`
`2021-07-03,187008`

So obviously that's the issue why Postgres is handling it that way...

Comment: Your query is returning about 85% of the table.  An index is not useful in this situation.

Comment: Yes, your index will not work if data is not sparse enough. Using index is useless and this is expected postgres behaviour

Comment: Using an index would most likely slow down the query. You could force the database to use the index and get the query plan. SET enable_seqscan TO off;

Comment: You need to keep in mind what a index is and what it does. Stripped to the lowest level, it is an operating system file on disk containing the address within another operating system file which needs to be read for the main data. Thus, worst case, 2 physical IOs (the slowest operation possible) may be required for each row. For queries needing only a small percent of the data the overhead *cost* of 2 IOs is worth it, but for any significant percent of the data just streaming (with OS read ahead functionality)  the data will be much much faster.  85% qualifies as  a significant percent.